# must define scaler variable in a SQL INSERT statement

Tags: sql, variables, insert, scalar

I am trying to write my code that has 3 text boxes and I need the information that is typed into the boxes to be passed over to a SQL database, which will then be shown in a gridview, functioning as a shopping cart. I keep getting an error in my catch block that is saying I have to define a scalar variable of @strItemName. Here is my code...any help would be really appreciated.Sorry if this code isn't quite formatted right on the site, this is my first post. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strItemName = txtTitle.Text;
        string strMovieQuantity = txtNumMovies.Text;
        string strMoviePrice = txtPrice.Text;
        //string strCurrentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        // I need this later to have a current user also inserted into the table



        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs3200"].ToString();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        string strSql = "INSERT INTO ShoppingCart ([ItemName], [QuantityOrdered], [UnitPrice]) VALUES  (@strItemName, @strQuantityOrdered, @strUnitPrice)";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, myConnection);



        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            int intCnt = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (intCnt > 1)
            {
                lblInsert.Text = intCnt.ToString() + "Records was added";
            }
            else
            {
                lblInsert.Text = "One Record was inserted";
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblInsert.Text = "Unable to insert your record" + "</br>";
            lblInsert.Text += "Error Message = " + ex.Message;
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add()...  completely missing...

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the parameters before calling the ExecuteNonQuery() method.

```
 using(SqlConnection myConnection=new SqlConnection(cnStr))
   {
   using(SqlCommand myCommand=new SqlCommand(strSql,myConnection))
    {
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strItemName",value1);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strQuantityOrdered",value2);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strUnitPrice",value3);
    myConnection.Open();
    int intCnt = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ....
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "prepared statements" (always advisable), you need to do something like this:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

  ```
  rConn.Open()
  Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("", rConn)
  ' Create and prepare an SQL statement.
  command.CommandText = "insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) values (@id, @desc)"
  command.Parameters.Add("@id", id)
  command.Parameters.Add("@desc", desc)
  command.Prepare() ' Calling Prepare after having set the Commandtext and parameters.
  command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  ```

If you just want a simple "insert", then you could do something like this:

```
string sql = 
  "insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) values ('" + id +
  "', '" + desc + "')";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```